# Delayed indexing in postgres

Tags: postgresql

We have a system which stores data in a postgres database. In some cases, the size of the database has grown to several GBs.

When this system is upgraded, the data in the said database is backed up, and finally it's restored in the database. Owing to the huge amounts of data, the indexing takes a long time to complete (~30 minutes) during restoration, thereby delaying the upgrade process.

Is there a way where the data copy and indexing can be split into two steps, where the data is copied first to complete the upgrade, followed by indexing which can be done at a later time in the background?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do it with `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. But `pg_restore`'s `-j` option helps a lot.

There is `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`. But `pg_restore` doesn't use it.

It would be quite nice to be able to restore everything except secondary indexes not depended on by FK constraints. Then restore those as a separate phase using `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`. But no such support currently exists, you'd have to write it yourself.

You can, however, filter the table-of-contents used by `pg_restore`, so you could possibly do some hacky scripting to do the needed work.

Comment: We use `psql` to restore the backed up data. Would `pg_restore`'s `-j` option be relatively better than `psql`? Also, does `psql` use/support `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`?

Comment: `psql` typically just runs whatever `pg_dump` produced, and it's `pg_dump` that'd need to create that. No, it doesn't. Yes, `-j` will help. Use `pg_dump -Fc` and use parallel restore mode with `pg_restore -j`.

Comment: Can the 'CREATE INDEX' commands be removed from the file produced by pg_dump and put in a different file, for execution later? Would this approach work at all? Would there be ordering issues?

Comment: The `--section` option in `pg_restore` lets you restore the data and indexes separately. The question is if restoring the indexes via `--section` would start creating the indexes or not. If it would, then I can restore the data first, and restore the indexes later.

Comment: The trouble with that is that `--section` is a bit indescriminate, it's not fine-grained enough. The `post-data` section also includes triggers, rules, and constraints, which you probably don't want to skip restoring before you activate. Hence my comment that you could possibly do it by ToC filtering, but it's awkward and clumsy. And yes, there could easily be ordering issues: you'd have to make sure you created any indexes required by constraints (e.g. secondary unique indexes used by foreign key constraints), so it's not as simple as "skip all create index statements"

Comment: What's the difference between using and not using `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` to restore the postgres data with `psql`? In both cases, the `psql` command would not complete till after the indexing is done, right? Only in the former case, the database is available for access to read/write before it is "fully" restored, correct?

Comment: @Maddy Right, it takes weaker locks so concurrent reads and writes are possible, albeit without using indexes that are still being created. If you were using `pg_restore` (like you should) you'd also be building indexes in parallel. Note, though, that `create index concurrently` is also *slower* to build indexes. So it's a trade-off.

Comment: I tried to restore only data from the backed up file, via `pg_restore -c -U postgres -e -a dump-Fc.sql > /dev/null`, but the size of the database did not change as a result. I checked the size of the database from which the dump was generated. The size of `dump-Fc.sql` is 1GB, and the database itself is 21GB.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

There is an option to separate the data and creating index in postgresql while taking pg_dump. 
Here **pre-data** refers to Schema, **post-data** refers to index and triggers.

From the docs,

> --section=sectionname Only dump the named section. The section name can be pre-data, data, or post-data. This option can be specified more
>   than once to select multiple sections. The default is to dump all
>   sections.
>
> The data section contains actual table data, large-object contents,
>   and sequence values. Post-data items include definitions of indexes,
>   triggers, rules, and constraints other than validated check
>   constraints. Pre-data items include all other data definition items.

May be this would help :)